# Измерение времени работы кода под Windows на c++

Tags: winapi, время, c++

Здравствуйте, подскажите WinApi функцию получения текущего времени с разрешением хотя бы до миллисекунд, которую можно использовать для измерения работы участка кода,  аналогичную System.currentTimeMillis() на джаве. Или подскажите best practice для решения таких задач. Пробовал использовать getTickCount(), но она позволяет измерить время работы всей системы, а не только текущего потока.

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis() и GetTickCount() совершенно аналогичны с той лишь разницей, что время отсчитывается от другого момента.

Comment: Нет смысла измерять околоквантовые длительности. Профилирование должно выполняться за интервалы, много больше десятков мс.

Comment: Должны быть идентичны, но между измерениями задать sleep, то джава всегда выдает одинаковые результаты точно равные длине sleep'a. А GetTickCount - каждый раз разные и иногда меньшие, чем длина слипа.

Answer (score 1):

Или QueryPerformanceCounter:

```
LARGE_INTEGER frequency, start, finish;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&finish);

// Время в миллисекундах
float delay = (finish.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) * 1000.0f / frequency.QuadPart;
```

Или напрямую RDTSC:

```
unsigned int start, finish;

start  = __rdtsc();
finish = __rdtsc();

// Время в тактах
unsigned int ticks = finish - start;
```

Comment: Так эти функции возвращают реальное или виртуальное (т.е. тики выделенные процессу) время ?

Comment: Вариант с rdtsc не годится для этой цели так как на некоторых процессорах TSC могут быть рассинхронизованы между ядрами\процессорами, что может привести к серьёзным отклонениям в ихмерениях и даже выдавать отрицательные времена выполнения.

Comment: Виртуальное время выполнения не может быть измерено достаточно точно, так как едва ли планировщик будет достаточно часто обновлять соответствующие поля. Наиболее вероятно, что планировщик обновляет их при переключении задач, что совсем не точно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть один очень легкий способ измерить время до миллисекунд:

> Библиотека `#include "time.h"`
>
> Перед началом самого кода: `int c=clock();`
> Мы даем переменной С или любой другой время сейчас.
> А в самом конце кода: `cout<<clock()-c<<endl;`

Вот и все.